# Why can't I get the text value from an input box?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So I was trying to get the text from the input box and set it as the header text. But I couldn't do it. I've been struggling with HTML DOM. Thank you.

```js
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById('header1').innerHTML = 'CHANGED';
}

document.getElementById('button2').onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById('input').value = document.getElementById('header1').innerHTML;
}
```

```html
   <div>
        <h1 id = 'header1'>HTML DOM</h1>
        <button id = 'button'>Click</button>
        <script src = 'app.js'></script>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id = 'input'>
        <button id = 'button2'>OK</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's seems to work?

Comment: I think it's working fine only

Comment: document.getElementById('input') - i don't see any element on the page with the id="input" there is an input element - so you probably want to either give the input an id attribute or use getElementsByTagName("input")[0]

Comment: In your `button2` click event, you assign header's `innerHTML`  to your input. You need to assign input's value to the header's `innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

You should change the function to this:

```
document.getElementById('button2').onclick = function(){
  document.getElementById('header1').innerHTML = document.getElementById('input').value
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the text provided in the input and set it as the header then you need to reverse your statement

```
document.getElementById('header1').innerText = document.getElementById('input').value;
```

Btw. if your input should be treated as just text then use the property .innerText and not .innerHtml

Answer (score 0):

You probably have interchanged assignment in your second function. Try this:

```js
document.getElementById('button2').onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById('header1').innerHTML = document.getElementById('input').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work too

```
document.getElementById('button2').onclick = function(){
  document.getElementById('header1').innerText=document.getElementById('input').value
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you, look at the my code snippet

```js
//function on button2 click event
document.getElementById('button2').onclick = function(){

    var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
    document.getElementById('header1').innerHTML=input;
}
```

```html
<p>From input to <b>header</b> on click button "OK"</p>  
  
  <div>
        <h1 id = 'header1'>HTML DOM</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id = 'input'>
        <button id = 'button2'>OK</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I saw that your code worked, I tried to write the code myself so in my code editor I commented out your code and wrote exactly the same code as yours and it didn't work for some reason. I am very mad at Javascript right now.But Many Thanks! Thank you.

Comment: EDIT : I realised that I wrote 'ondclick' instead of 'onclick'. I am so careless these days.

Comment: Sometimes it happens, you don't notice such little things, but they play an important role. Good luck in the future!